# Bitnami Wordpress: Installing theme error 'Could not copy file'

Tags: wordpress-theming, bitnami, wordpress

I have downloaded the Bitnami Wordpress stack (https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress). It all seems to have installed perfectly fine. I go into wordpress on my browser and log in. I have purchased a wordpress theme which I know works because I have used it before in a different project. When I go 'Appearence > Themes > Add new > Upload theme' then upload my .zip file of my theme I get the following result:

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not copy file. shopkeeper/settings/redux/ReduxCore/assets/css/vendor/jquery-ui-bootstrap/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png

I have read that this is probably due to the permissions settings but any solutions I find don't appear to be applicable to the Bitnami Wordpress stack.

I am relatively new to Wordpress and website development but I couldn't find a solution, or at least not one I could understand. I really appreciate any ideas as to how to fix this.

Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

When I click update on a plugin I was asked to FTP and after a few hours it hit me.
I fixed it by setting the hostname to "localhost" instead of using the IP.

This is because there was a loop happening and making the file upload fail and that's logged in the /var/log/vsftpd.log

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is probably due to permissions.
You can find a section with some help in the Bitnami Wiki:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress/Troubleshooting_WordPress#Wordpress_Plugins_Troubleshooting

Basically, connect to your server and execute the following, replacing '[installdir]' for the path to the installation directory of Bitnami Wordpress Stack:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon [installdir]/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
sudo chmod -R g+w [installdir]/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
```

You can also visit our community forum, focused on solving issues and questions about Bitnami Stacks so we don't fill StackOverflow with very specific questions not programming related ;)
https://community.bitnami.com

Disclaimer: I work at Bitnami

Comment: I had to set permissions to `daemon:daemon` to fix this error